Does there exist a group $G$ such that $(G\setminus S)^2=G$ for each $S\subseteq G$ with $|S|<\infty$?
Note: I have answered this question myself in typing it up. I thought I'd share it because it took me too long. Maybe someone will benefit from it.
The Question:

Does there exist a group $G$ such that $(G\setminus S)^2=G$ for each $S\subseteq G$ with $|S|<\infty$?

Here $X^2=\{ab\mid a,b\in X\}$ for each set $X$.
Thoughts:
I'm not sure.
The group would have to be infinite (since, otherwise, take $S=G$).
The first candidate I could think of is $\Bbb Z$, which works fine, I guess; we have
$$(\Bbb Z\setminus S)^2:=\{s+t\mid s,t\in \Bbb Z\setminus S\},$$
which has me thinking of sets like, say, $\{-x,x\}$ for $x\neq 0$.  But we could get $\pm x$ back using $\pm x=(\pm x-y)+y$ for $y\neq \pm x$. How about $S=[-x, x]\cap\Bbb Z$? We can use the sake trick: take $y\notin S$ and then $\pm z=(\pm z-y)+y$.
Perhaps I could do an exhaustive, case-wise search of types of finite subsets of $\Bbb Z$, but I see no obvious way to partition the set of all its finite subsets in such a way that it would help.
My suspicion is that, if it doesn't work for $\Bbb Z$ (or, maybe, all free groups), then no examples exist.
Motivation:
I can't share exactly what inspired the question. I weakened the axioms of something I'm exploring for my research. You know how it is: "divide and conquer"!
I think this is interesting in its own right though.

The same trick works (with a little adjustment)!
Let $S$ be a finite subset of $\Bbb Z$.  Then, for any $s\in S$, we have
$$s=(s-y)+y\in (\Bbb Z\setminus S)^2$$
for any $y\notin S$ with $|y|>\max\{|t|\mid t\in S\}$, which will always exist as $\Bbb Z\setminus S$ is infinite.

Wouldn't any infinite group be an example using a similar trick? Because $x=(xy^{-1})y$ and we can just pick $y$ such that $xy^{-1}$ and $y$ are both not in $S$ . . .

It follows from the Pigeonhole Principle and the Latin Square property.
